# Given distances from a point inside a rectangle to all the vertices, and ratio of sides, find sides of rectangle.

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given the distances from a point inside a rectangle to all the vertices, and also given the ratio of the rectangle's width to height, is it possible to find the sides of the rectangle?

Comment: I think so. Place the inside point at the origin, then every distance $d_i$ you give to each vertex is $d_i^2=x_i^2+y_i^2$. You then have 4 equations with 8 unknowns. But for every vertex you can make an additional equation: the dot product of the two adjacent sides of that vertex must be 0 (right angle requirement). Then you have 8 equations for 8 unknowns.

Comment: Yes, it should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $ABCD$ is the rectangle, and $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ the given distances of internal point $P$ from $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$. Drop from $P$ perpendiculars $PM$ on $AB$ and $PN$ on $AD$ and set:
$$
m=AB,\quad km=AD,\quad x=AM,\quad y=AN,
$$
where $k=AD/AB$ is the given ratio. Then one can write three equations for the three unknowns $x,y,m$:
$$
\cases{
a^2 = x^2 + y^2\\
b^2 = (m - x)^2 + y^2\\
d^2 = x^2 + (km - y)^2\\
}
$$
Substituting $x^2+y^2=a^2$ in the second and third equation, we can solve for $x$ and $y$ as a function of $m$:
$$
x={m^2+a^2-b^2\over2m},
\quad
y={k^2m^2+a^2-d^2\over2km}.
$$
Plugging these back into the first equation, we end up with a biquadratic equation for $m$:
$$
(1 + k^2)k^2 m^4-2(b^2+d^2)k^2 m^2+
a^4 - 2 a^2 d^2 + d^4 + a^4 k^2 - 2 a^2 b^2 k^2 + 
 b^4 k^2=0. 
$$
The solutions of this equation can then be readily found. Of course negative solutions must be discarded, and also solutions leading to negative values of $x$ or $y$, for in that case point $P$ would lie outside the rectangle.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It will take me a while to work through it. But thanks for the great assist.  I found this problem deceptively difficult.

Comment: Thanks so much again.  That does what I need.  I realize now that finding the (X,Y) coordinates of P is key.

Comment: I had to fix the sign on the term (b^2-d^2) to (b^2+d^2) but other than that this solution works great!

Comment: @Bob Thanks, corrected now.