# Is it possible to calculate the Area of a rectangle using the British Flag Theorem?

Tags: geometry

Is it possible to calculate the Area of a rectangle using the British Flag Theorem?

Suppose we were given an example of a rectangle ABCD, which has a point P inside. Given PA=5 , PB = 7 and PD = 1. We can easily work out that PC = 5. But is it possible to calculate the area of this rectangle ?

One another way of phrasing this question might be to think of this theorem's converse. Like is there only 1 unique rectangle which satisfies the given values. Like only 1 rectangle can be made using PA=5, PB=7, PC=5 and PD=1.

Comment: For those who (like me) had never heard of this theorem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_flag_theorem says, "In Euclidean geometry, the British flag theorem says that if a point P is chosen inside a rectangle ABCD then the sum of the squares of the Euclidean distances from P to two opposite corners of the rectangle equals the sum to the other two opposite corners."

Comment: See if this can be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4613789/255730

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose all four distances are equal, say, they are all $d$. Then $P$ could be at the center of a square of side $d\sqrt2$ and area $2d^2$. But it could also be at the center of a rectangle with sides $a,b$ with $a^2+b^2=4d^2$ and area $ab$, which will be smaller than $2d^2$ unless $a=b=d\sqrt2$. E.g., we can take $d=5$, $a=6$, $b=8$, $ab=48\ne50=2d^2$.

Comment: Even with the example given  in the OP you can put PD up against the side of the rectangle, making its area $(0+\sqrt{24})(1+5) = 12\sqrt{6} \approx 29.39$ or at 45 degrees to get area $(\sqrt{1/2}+\sqrt{25-1/2})^2 = 32$.

Comment: Thank you! It slipped my mind that the angle between the lengths can be changed to give different rectangles, if the angles or the ratio of the sides were not mentioned.